# Explaining and Addressing the Bias-Variance Tradeoff

Tags: variance, bias, validation, bias-variance-tradeoff, training-error

Let's say we have a model whose training error is 7% and the validation error is 10%. What does this mean in terms of the bias-variance tradeoff? I know that high validation error and low training error means there is a high variance, but I'm not sure how to evaluate it when they are close together like this.

What next steps would you propose if you saw these error rates?

Alternatively, if I clearly had a case of high variance, what next steps should I take?

Comment: I think people erroneously think that training and validation error have to be the same.  Valdiation error is an estimate of the out of sample performance of the model.  If 10% is good enough for you, then you should move on to the next step of the pipeline.  In terms of the bias variance tradeoff, it is tough to say.  A less complex model may yield smaller validation error, it may not.  If all you present to me is the training and validation error I would conclude: There is a small amount of over fitting (as with everything).

Comment: After thinking about it a little more, could the training and validation error being close together and a little high mean there is some bias in the model?

Comment: If the training and validation are close together, that is good.  That means there is little overfitting.  If the training and validation error are large, it could mean the model is biased yes.  For example, linear regression is a high bias model; it can only estimate linear functions.  If the true outcome is non-linear, then the validation error would be large and you would be correct to attribute that to bias.